# Android How to make full screen Video?

Tags: android, html5-video, fullscreen

When I make a video full screen in WebView, the toolbar is not hidden. How can I hide it? Below you can see the codes I use.I'm using fragment and the navigation drawer menu.

When I make a video full screen in WebView, the toolbar is not hidden. How can I hide it? Below you can see the codes I use.I'm using fragment and the navigation drawer menu.
[Full screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jakA.png)

```
public class searchWebFragment extends Fragment {


public searchWebFragment() {

}

@Nullable
@Override

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchwb, container, false);

    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBarHome);
    final WebView webView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wv_home);
    final EditText araTxt = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.araTxt);
    final Button araBtn = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.araBtn);
    final TextView uyariTxt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.uyariTxt);

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int i, String s, String d1) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, url);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Dosya İndiriliyor", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
    webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    araBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String aranacaksey = araTxt.getText().toString();
            webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(false);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
            String url = "http://www.ifsalar.16mb.com/?s=" + aranacaksey;
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            araTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            araBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            uyariTxt.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });





    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

}

Comment: What client are you using for your WebView? Can you please share your code

Comment: @Nero sir, can you hear me?

Comment: Yes I am here, what's up?

Comment: I shared my mistake for browser_home.java did you see that?

Comment: clean your project

Comment: join this room for discussion instead of filling up this page with comments - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181002/discussion-between-nero-and-arthur-frank-asabiyovic

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try out the follow code and remove the listeners which are related to loading the contents of your WebView.

You need to implement the method to load the website in your webview first.

```
private void loadWebsite() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        mWebView.loadUrl("yourURL");
    } else {
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

From here, you need to implement 2 different class "Browser_Home" and "MyChrome". For testing purposes, just write it outside searchWebFragment and later on you can implement it as a separate java file. With only the Browser_Home class, the fullscreen button will be disabled. When MyChrome class is added, fullscreen button is enabled and toolbar should disappear as intended.

```
class Browser_home extends WebViewClient {

    Browser_home() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        setTitle(view.getTitle());
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

    }
}

private class MyChrome extends WebChromeClient {

    private View mCustomView;
    private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
    protected FrameLayout mFullscreenContainer;
    private int mOriginalOrientation;
    private int mOriginalSystemUiVisibility;

    MyChrome() {}

    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster()
    {
        if (mCustomView == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getApplicationContext().getResources(), 2130837573);
    }

    public void onHideCustomView()
    {
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).removeView(this.mCustomView);
        this.mCustomView = null;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility);
        setRequestedOrientation(this.mOriginalOrientation);
        this.mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = null;
    }

    public void onShowCustomView(View paramView, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback paramCustomViewCallback)
    {
        if (this.mCustomView != null)
        {
            onHideCustomView();
            return;
        }
        this.mCustomView = paramView;
        this.mOriginalSystemUiVisibility = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
        this.mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        this.mCustomViewCallback = paramCustomViewCallback;
        ((FrameLayout)getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(this.mCustomView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(-1, -1));
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(3846);
    }
}
```

And finally, apply the following functions and attributes to your webview and give it another try. Remember to apply these within your OnCreate method:

```
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new Browser_home());
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    loadWebsite();
```

Let me know if this works and I can credit the corresponding person for the assistance with the code and classes.

Comment: What is 2130837573 ?

Comment: The resource id of the image data - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory#decodeResource(android.content.res.Resources,%20int)

Comment: I know, but why do you know that number?

Answer (score 0):

create a folder `row` and copy the video on raw folder on resources and do the following steps,

On your XML file add `VideoView`,

```
   <VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vdoPlayer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

On your .java class file do,

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://Your package name Here/" + R.raw.welcome_video);
 vdoPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.setLooping(true);
     }
 });
 vdoPlayer.setVideoURI(uri);
 vdoPlayer.start();
```